# Why am I getting memory leakage when i am simpy doing setContentView(R.layout.somelayout)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, out-of-memory, virtual-memory

in my onCreate(), i am simply using an xml as a content view for the activity. why am i getting a memory leak. is it something i am doing wrong?

My xml simply has 5 image buttons, with a statelistdrawable (selector) for each imagebutton. each image is just 16kb in size. (So i am using 10 images- a pressed state image and an normal state image for each button).

Nowhere in my activity am i using LayoutInflator..
Shouldn't android be recycling bimaps on its own when setting the content view from xml?

I am getting error something like this:

```
02-17 09:18:39.797: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{***.***.*****.activity/***.***.*****.home.HomeScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1620)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at ***.***.*****.home.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(HomeScreenActivity.java:35)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     ... 11 more
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:171)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     ... 21 more
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:322)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:688)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1710)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1846)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1795)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:282)
02-17 09:18:39.817: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(372):     ... 25 more
```

I replaced the images, and the code worked without the application hanging up, but stikll my ddms log was going crazy with the following errors:

```
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/(372): VM won't let us allocate 270000 bytes
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(372): 270000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/(372): VM won't let us allocate 270000 bytes
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(372): 270000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/(372): VM won't let us allocate 270000 bytes
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(372): 270000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/(372): VM won't let us allocate 270000 bytes
02-17 09:18:37.287: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(372): 264600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
```

..
.
.
.
.

Although the app is working, i would like to know what i am doing wrong. or is it a bug in the buggy android system?

attaching the code:

```
public class VirtualHomeActivity extends Activity  {

    ImageButton imgbtn1, imgbtn2, imgbtn3, imgbtn4,
            imgbtn5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
}
}
```

layout home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/home_screen_animation_controller" android:background="@drawable/bg_application">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
        android:layout_width="340dip" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:background="@drawable/custombutton1"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_below="@id/imgBtn1"
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn2" android:layout_width="340dip" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:background="@drawable/custombutton2"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:layout_below="@id/imgBtn2      android:id="@+id/imgBtn3" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_width="340dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:background="@drawable/custombutton3"></ImageButton>
<ImageButton android:layout_below="@id/imgBtnS3" android:id="@+id/imgBtn4" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="340dip" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:background="@drawable/custombutton4"></ImageButton>
<ImageButton android:layout_below="@id/imgBtn4"
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn5" android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="340dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:background="@drawable/custombutton5"></ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the selector is:(custombutton1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_clicked" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_unclicked" /> </selector>
```

i removed all other code from the activity to check whether i was creating a memory leak. But here i am jsut setting content view as my layout file, and still my ddms says VM won't let us allocate 270000 bytes

i dont think i tried to manage any activity life cycles here.

Comment: It's not an ANdroid bug, your application must be leaking memory somehow, or you are loading too many bitmaps. Note that the size of an image on disk does NOT matter (at least not enough.) The resolution of the images matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory leak may be somewhere else, perhaps in how you are managing activity lifecycle changes. Take a look at the article [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Comment: that activity is the first activity in the application, and the code is nothing but onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onCreate(savedIntanceState); setContentView(R.layout.home);}}